# Unable to negotiate with port 22: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha1

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been researching this and have looked at some other posts but don't know what is going on here.

When I try to SFTP into another server I am getting an error with no matching MAC found. I ran a `ssh -Q mac` and see that the `hmac-sha1` is there. I also checked the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and see no MAC arguments. What else can I check to see what is causing this issue?

`SSH -vvv` to the destination server

````
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version CrushFTPSSHD
debug1: no match: CrushFTPSSHD
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,ext-info-s
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
Unable to negotiate with  port 22: no matching MAC found. Their offer: hmac-sha1```


ssh -Q mac             
hmac-sha1
hmac-sha1-96
hmac-sha2-256
hmac-sha2-512
hmac-md5
hmac-md5-96
hmac-ripemd160
hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
umac-64@openssh.com
umac-128@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com
hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com
umac-64-etm@openssh.com
umac-128-etm@openssh.com
````

Comment: Issue was in the /etc/ssh/ssh_config. I was looking at the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and wasn't finding the MAC parameter.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR *i was getting*

> ssh admin@192.168.122.41

*Unable to negotiate with 192.168.122.41 port 22: no matching MAC found.
Their offer: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512*

SOLUTION
Ubuntu 22 users... please note that it's related to the client capabilities issue when you login to devices with lower ssh standard (such as cisco router IOS 17.3.6) ...

Solution - simply do

> sudo nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Uncomment 1-2 params near the bottom section in the above mentioned ssh_config file ( 'or' simple paste the following at the bottom of the file without uncommenting anything). choice is yours

> Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
> MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512

This should do it.
In case, issue still persists check what's the offer you're receiving from the remote device that you're told while doing ssh.

Is it about the cipher ?
or
Is it about the keys ?

just uncomment the required param (cipher or mac) what you've and add the suffix required(by the remote device.
Hope this helps